# Save multiple inputs with same name to different rows in cakePHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have some group of inputs each with same name, as shown in the picture[image]

I want to save each category with each number of rooms and standard rate. All category inputs have the same name (`<input name="category[]">`) same for No. of rooms and standard rate.

So far I've tried:

```
foreach($data['category'] as $cat){
 $this->Model->save($cat)
//Will save only categories without No. of rooms and standard rate.
}
```

Is there a way I can `foreach` through the 3 groups of inputs and save data in different rows accordingly? My table columns are named after inputs name.

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: @ drmonkeyninja version 2.5.7

Comment: I think you need saveMany http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: @Michel thanks. See my answer below. Remember to always include the Cake version number in future.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to achieve using the [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) and [`saveMany`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array). Firstly in your View you want to include the form elements using the FormHelper using something like:-

```
echo $this->Form->input('Model..category');
```

Where you need to replace `Model` with your model alias. The `..` will cause it to output an input with a name like `Model[][category]`. If you want to control the numeric index (for example in a loop to associate it with other fields) you can change this to `$this->Form->input('Model.1.category')` which would produce an input with the name `Model[1][category]`.

Then in your controller you can save this data using `saveMany`:-

```
$this->Model->saveMany($this->request->data);
```

Again replacing `Model` with your model's alias.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to send this type of format to your controller, then you can use saveMany() function in Caek php "

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

```
$data = array(
   array('field1' => 'valuea', 'field2' => 'valuea'),
   array('field1' => 'valueb', 'field2' => 'valueb'),
   array('field1' => 'valuec', 'field2' => 'valuec')
)
```

or in

```
 $data = array(
    array('Model' => array('field1' => 'valuea', 'field2' =>  'valuea')),
  array('Model' => array('field1' => 'valueb', 'field2' => 'valueb')),
  array('Model' => array('field1' => 'valuec', 'field2' => 'valuec'))
 )
```

format.

You can do like this
$this->Model->saveMany($data);